# Display different data every other two cols

Tags: php, arrays, intervals

I have these images and videos data that I stored in array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 81
            [media] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file_type] => 2
                            [file_name] => accident-damaged-car-5be9304f2b429.png
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [file_type] => 2
                            [file_name] => xdamaged-car-640x360jpgpagespeedicsgjldiwfmp-5be930504fb14.jpg
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [file_type] => 1
                            [file_name] => broken-car-5be9305055d13.mp4
                        )

                )

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 82
            [media] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file_type] => 2
                            [file_name] => accident-damaged-car-5be9304f2b340.png
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [file_type] => 1
                            [file_name] => broken-car-5be9305055d14.mp4
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

So I wanted to display the images and videos intermittently every other 2 cols. For example, the first 2 cols will display images and the next 2 cols will display videos and the next 2 cols will display images and so on. The output should be as in the picture below.

[image]

I will foreach the data and filter them by their `file_type (1=video, 2=image)`. But how should I display them like in the picture?

P.S : Every data has multiple images and videos but I only want to display 1 image or 1 video to be shown when I display them.

Comment: So you want the first picture to be from `id=81`, second from `id=82`, then 2 video from `id=83` and `id=84` and so on OR you just want all the picture and video on pairs without care about the ordering?

Comment: @DavidWinder Yes correct. first picture to be from id=81, second from id=82, then 2 video from id=83 and id=84 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your array and pick every time the media type according the `Mod 4` of your current position.

Consider the following code:

```
function getFileNameByType($files, $type) {
    foreach($files as $file)
        if ($file["file_type"] == $type)
            return $file["file_name"];
}

$ans = array();
foreach($arr as $elem){
    $type = (count($ans) % 4 == 0 || count($ans) % 4 == 1) ? "2" : "1";
    $ans[] = getFileNameByType($elem["media"] ,$type);
}
```

If you put this as input:

```
$arr = array(array("id"=>82, "media"=>array(array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "aaa.png"), array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "bbb.jpg"), array("file_type"=>1, "file_name"=> "ccc.mp4"))), array("id"=>83, "media"=>array(array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "ddd.png"), array("file_type"=>1, "file_name"=> "eee.mp4"))), array("id"=>84, "media"=>array(array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "fff.png"), array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "ggg.jpg"), array("file_type"=>1, "file_name"=> "hhh.mp4"))), array("id"=>85, "media"=>array(array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "iii.png"), array("file_type"=>2, "file_name"=> "jjj.jpg"), array("file_type"=>1, "file_name"=> "kkk.mp4"))));
```

You will get the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaa.png
    [1] => ddd.png
    [2] => hhh.mp4
    [3] => kkk.mp4
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're awesome! It really helps me to save my time. Thank you so much :)